# How to access local folders in ajax using file:///F:/foldername ? But it works for http://

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Here I dynamically creating a file name list using AJAX jQuery using following code!

```
$(window).load(function () {
    var fileExt = ".csv";
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'file:///F:/foldername/',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                $("#fileNames").html('<ul>');
                $(data).find("a:contains(" + fileExt + ")").each(function () {
                    $("#fileNames").append('<li><input id=\'chckId\' type = \'checkbox\'/>' + $(this).text() + '</li>');
                });
                $("#fileNames").append('</ul>');
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<div id='fileNames' class="panel-body" style="display: block;"></div>
```

Comment: You cannot programmatically access the local filesystem from JS code - it would be a *massive* security flaw if you could.

Comment: But file:///f:/foldername can able to access in browser. But not able access in js  ! Why?

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

Most browsers will block access (by XMLHttpRequest) to the local file system entirely, and those that don't do not provide a mechanism for reading directories.

---

For example:

Chrome says:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/me/tmp/. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Firefox says:

> NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied

… although for a *file* rather than a directory, it **will** list the content (providing the file is in or under the same directory as the HTML document).

---

> But f:///foldername can able to access in browser. But not able access in js ! Why?

Giving access to data on your hard disk to you, as the person controlling the browser, is different from giving access to that data to some JavaScript in a file that you might have downloaded from anywhere and which might do anything with it (such as sending it to the person who wrote the JS). See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553500/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-https-www-website-com/35553666#35553666).

Comment: Can you please help me to list filename in jquery?

Comment: @PRADEEP — Please read the very first two words of this answer again.

Comment: I need a help in Ruby on Rails

Comment: RoR has absolutely nothing to do with anything you mentioned in the question. If you need help with it then [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).